# NodeJS is already installed but won't run

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, vps, apt

I'm running Ubuntu 18 on my VPS server, and I'm trying to run NodeJS, however, this happens:

```
seth@vps186104:~$ nodejs -v

Command 'nodejs' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs

seth@vps186104:~$ sudo apt install nodejs
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
nodejs is already the newest version (8.10.0~dfsg-2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
seth@vps186104:~$
```

It says to install the package to run nodejs, however, trying to install nodejs it says it's already installed
What is going on?

Comment: Sounds like a path issue

Comment: what does: `node -v` output?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande

seth@vps186104:~$ node -v

Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs

Comment: It's weird, just pulled a docker image from ubuntu 18:04, didn't have any issue. Have you tried installing it from source?

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande No. Should I/

Comment: You could try, but to be sure, have you tried rebooting the server? Maybe it is installed, but ubuntu for some reason failed to locate the binary in that session. And try `npm -v` too please.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande after restarting the server, nodejs isn't recognized, but is supposedly still installed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172187/discussion-between-marcos-casagrande-and-seth-painter).

Comment: Does it provide a path when performing `which node` or `which nodejs`? Sounds like the install path isn't in your shell's path for commands to run. Note this may help if it is a path issue: https://askubuntu.com/questions/881691/node-bash-path-confusion-on-ubuntu-16-using-n/881719#881719

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

Or if you want node 10.

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```