# nodejs is already the newest version but node -v showing error

Tags: node.js, linux, shell, command-line, ubuntu-18.04

if i type node -v in terminal its showing following error

```
Command 'node' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install nodejs
```

if i try above command its return following result

```
Building dependency tree 

Reading state information... Done

nodejs is already the newest version (8.11.3-1nodesource1).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 24 not upgraded.
```

By mistake i will change the permission of `/usr/bin/` folder i fix that issue but my node is not working...

Comment: Check this question [NodeJS is already installed but won't run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50633382/nodejs-is-already-installed-but-wont-run)

Comment: yes i am using Ubuntu @JonasLochmann

Comment: @ShahidMulani check the linked question, it's the exact same issue

Comment: i will check your suggestion @MarcosCasagrande but still not working node... :(

Comment: Weird, same problem, same OS.

Comment: hello @MarcosCasagrande ... By mistake i changed /usr/bin/ folder's permission then i face another issue my sudo is not working i will fix that but my nodejs is making this type of issue plz help... thanks

Answer (score 0):

The nodejs package installs node as nodejs, so running `nodejs -v` should work. If you’re not planning on install the node package which is completely unrelated to NodeJS, you can link node to nodejs:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```